# fonction inverse of $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inverse, inverse-function

How can i show that the fonction inverse of $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x}$ is $\dfrac{x^{4}-4x^{2}+4}{4x^{2}}$
My attempt:
$$\begin{cases} f^{-1}(x)=y \\ 
x\in[\sqrt{2};+\infty)  
\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases} x=f(y) \\ 
x\in[0;+\infty)  
\end{cases} $$
\begin{align}
x=f(y) &\iff x=\sqrt{y+2}+\sqrt{y}\\
&\iff x^2=y+2+y+2\sqrt{(y+2)y}\\
&\iff x^2=2y+2+2\sqrt{(y+2)y}\\
&\iff \frac{x^2}{2}=y+1+\sqrt{(y+2)y}\\
&\iff \frac{x^2}{2}-1=y+\sqrt{(y+2)y}\\
\end{align}

Comment: If you have an expression for $f^{-1}(x)$, couldn't you just use the property that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and plug in to confirm your solution?

Comment: no because I just used the wolfram to know the $f^{-1}$

Comment: At your last step, move the $y$ over and square again. There's still a bit of algebra to be done after that, but it's not too bad.

Comment: do you have optimal way to find quickly the solution

Comment: Note that $y+\sqrt{(y+2)y}=\sqrt y\cdot x$. From here it is easy to finish

Comment: @am301 I can't proceed with it please, can you put solution

Comment: I wrote an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $x\ge0$ and $y\ge\sqrt2$, $$(y-\sqrt x)^2=y^2-2\sqrt xy+x=(\sqrt{x+2})^2=x+2$$ gives

$$\sqrt x=\frac{y^2-2}{2y}.$$

Comment: What should I elaborate ? The solution is very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Per the request of the OP, here is solution based directly on his approach. His last line is:
$$
\frac x2-1=y+\sqrt{(y+2)y}=\sqrt y(\sqrt y+\sqrt{y+2})=\sqrt y\cdot x
$$
Squaring both sides:
$$
\frac{(x^2-2)^2}4=x^2y
$$
or:
$$
\frac{(x^2-2)^2}{4x^2}=y
$$

Answer (score 1):

You have reached a good point:
$$\frac{x^2}{2}-1=y+\sqrt{(y+2)}y\implies 
\frac{x^2}{2}-1-y=\sqrt{(y+2)}y\implies \frac{x^4}{4}+1+y^2-x^2-x^2 y+2y=y^2+2y$$
Here, we have simply squared both sides, knowing that LHS and RHS are always greater or equal to $0$ with your contrainst.

Now, we have to solve for $y$. We obtain:
$$\implies \frac{x^4}{4}+1-x^2-x^2 y=0 \implies \frac{x^4+4-4x^2}{4}=x^2 y\implies y=f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x^4-4x^2+4}{4x^2}$$